# My if statement is not working. The condition is not being evaluated. I have no idea why

Tags: python, if-statement

```
if len(enterlist) == 0:
    print('no list')
elif 5.5<=9.32 or 9.6:
    print('sell')
    closelist.append([driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').text])
else:
    print('no list no sell')
```

sell
I have the above code. It prints sell when it should print the next line. I am building the script in sublime with python, but do not know why it will not work.

Comment: `elif 5.5<=9.32 or 9.6:` does not work the way you think it does. In plain English, what exactly are you *intending* for it to do? Why not just `5.5 <= 9.6`? Wouldn't that cover the case where `5.5 <= 9.32` as well?

Comment: Why are you comparing hard-coded numbers instead of variables?

Answer (score 1):

```
elif 5.5<=9.32 or 9.6:
```

is evaluated as

- if either of these is true:

  - 5.5 <= 9.32
  - 9.6 is truthy

and nonzero numbers (such as 9.6) always are truthy.

You might be looking for

```
elif 5.5 <= 9.32 or 5.5 <= 9.6:
```

Comment: ... which is pretty much equivalent to `else:`

Answer (score 0):

It will always print sell if len(enterlist) == 0 is false

Here is why

the second if condition is always true because 5.5<=9.32 is always true. The problem is that you wrote a comparison between numbers (not variables) and if the universe is not going to change its' laws then 9.32 is always bigger than 5.5.